# Types of Normality Test used in Minitab

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, normality-assumption

I recently performed a normality test for a set of data.
I noticed that when I use the AD test, the p-value is < 0.05; whereas when I use RJ test, the p-value showed is >0.05.

My question here is: should I conclude my data has a normal distribution, based on RJ test or a non-normal on based on the AD test?

Comment: Shapiro-Wilks is usually used to test for normality.

Comment: A non-rejection of a null hypothesis generally does not mean that the null hypothesis is true, so *no* test can tell you that your data has a normal distribution. (And anyway nothing in real life has a perfect normal distribution, so you know your data are non-normal without testing.) The best any test can do is to say that, according to the test statisic, *if* the underlying distribution were normal, data could realistically look like yours (non-rejection), or that something like your data wouldn't be expected under normality (in case of rejection).

Answer (score 1):

No test will perform well in all scenarios. But some might have a better overall performance.For example, from the [Minitab Blog](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/the-statistical-mentor/anderson-darling-ryan-joiner-or-kolmogorov-smirnov-which-normality-test-is-the-best), when testing three different scenarios:

> In summary, the Anderson-Darling test was never the worst test, but it
>   was not nearly as effective as the RJ test at detecting a 4-sigma
>   outlier. If you're analyzing data from a manufacturing process tends
>   to produce individual outliers, the Ryan-Joiner test is the most
>   appropriate.
>
> The RJ test performed very well in two of the scenarios, but was poor
>   at detecting Non-Normality when there was a shift in the data. If
>   you're analyzing data from a manufacturing process that tends to shift
>   due to unexpected changes, the AD test is the most appropriate.
>
> The KS test did not perform well in any of the scenarios.

Still, Minitab only offers three types of tests, but [there are many other options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test). And [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00949655.2010.520163) you can get a more thorough analysis of some of them.